# How to add custom query to Form

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a form the purpose of which is to create many-to-many records (in a linking table) between two tables. (Tutor Session on the left, Students the on the right. There can be more than one student in a session, thus the need for the linking table.)  This actually works just fine as it is.  However, the Student Table is based on a query which brings back only certain records. (The students associated with the Totor.) However, in some cases, I need to change out that query to bring back ALL students.

So what I need is to hook up a checkbox.  When the user checks the box, it brings back all students, and when it is not, it brings back the usual records.

So the question is, how do I swap out a query at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MattThalman is basically correct. But the query designer in LightSwitch doesn't really have a way to easily do what he's described. The Filter part doesn't have the ability to short circuit the Where. So you need to write some code to achieve what he's described.

You would need two parameters, a boolean `GetAllStudents` and a `Tutor`. They can be optional or not, that's up to you. But if they are optional, then a `null` check is necessary. Then click Write Code and select the query's `_PreprocessQuery` method.

In your `_PreprocessQuery`, check your boolean and only perform a filter query using LINQ if you don't want all students. Otherwise, let the `PreprocessQuery` fall through and you will get all of the records.

The code should look something like this:

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub StudentsInSession_PreprocessQuery(ByRef query As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of LightSwitchApplication.Student))
    'If GetAllStudents is not null or false, return students assigned to Tutor
    If ((GetAllStudents IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (GetAllStudents <> True)) Then
        query = From sis In query
                Where sis.Tutor = Tutor
                Select sis
    End If
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
partial void EmployeeBenefitsSet_All_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Student> query) {
    // If GetAllStudents is not null or false, return students assigned to Tutor
    if ((GetAllStudents != null) && (GetAllStudents != true)) {
        query = from sis in query
                where sis.Tutor == Tutor
                select sis;
    }
}
```

*Please note, I adapted this from something in my own code and used a translator to convert from VB.NET to C# since you didn't specify a language. You will obviously need to check for correctness.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need to dynamically swap out a query.  Just design a query that takes a Boolean parameter that indicates the state of the checkbox and have it return the data appropriately based on the value of that parameter.  So, for illustration purposes, here is some pseudo code of the where condition of such a query: (@GetAllStudents or Student.Tutor == @Tutor).  The @Tutor parameter would need to be marked as optional in that case.